# Criar divs dinamicamente (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, codeigniter, select

**Preciso criar varias divs dentro de um foreach na minha view, por enquanto está assim a view:**

```
<?php
    echo form_open('admin/marcacao/registraMarcacoes');
  ?>
    <div class="area-imagem">
      <img src="<?= $img?>" alt="<?= $img?>">
      <input style="display:none;" name="idImg" value="<?= $id?>">
      <?php foreach ($marcacoes->result() as $row) : ?>
        <div class="pixel" style="top:<?php echo $row->coordX ?>px; left:<?php echo $row->coordY ?>px"></div>
      <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
    <input style="display:none;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg my-5 mx-5" value="Registrar">
  <?php 
    echo form_close(); 
  ?>
```

**Meu controller está assim:**

```
function insereMarcacoes()
    {
        $dados['img'] = $this->input->post('src');
        $dados['id'] = $this->input->post('id');

        $this->load->model('admin/tbdmarcacao');
        $dados['marcacoes'] = $this->tbdmarcacao->listaMarcacoes();

        $this->load->view('admin/inserir_marcacoes', $dados);
    }
```

**E minha model desta maneira:**

```
function listaMarcacoes()
    {
        $id['idImagem'] = $this->input->post('id');

        $query = $this->db->select('*')
                            ->from('tbdmarcacao')
                            ->where('idImagem', $id)
                            ->get();

        return $query->result_array();


    }
```

**O problema, é que está retornando diversos erros, como mostra nesse print:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O problema está no Model. Note que `$id['idImagem'] = $this->input->post('id');` insere o valor do post no índice `idImagem` e no `where` da consulta é passado o array inteiro e não apenas o índice `id`. Então o where deve ficar assim: `->where('idImagem', $id['idImagem'])`.